# Cannot load class but can import works fine

Tags: java, scala

I have this `scala` code which returns empty iterator

```
val i = ServiceLoader.load(Class.forName("io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelProvider"), classOf[ManagedChannelProvider].getClassLoader )
```

which is equivalent to `java` code

```
Iterable i = ServiceLoader.load(Class.forName("io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelProvider"), ManagedChannelProvider.class.getClassLoader )
```

The project builds fine, but at runtime this iterable `i` is always empty. How do I make it load the actual class?

Also, when we provide all dependencies in the runtime rather than include them, this also works.

Comment: You still needs dependencies in the runtime, even if you load them dynamically like that. `ClassLoader` is still looking them up in the classpath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're confused about what ServiceLoader is for.

The point of serviceloader is to provide it an interface, and the serviceloader then returns an instance (created by calling the public no-args constructor) of each type 'registered' as being a service provider for that interface.

It does this by scanning the entire classpath for the file META-INF/services/io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelProvider (and you should never be using Class.forName for this; you should just use: `ServiceLoader.load(ThatInterface.class)`; if that is a compile time error because the interface isn't on your classpath, then fix that; serviceloader has nothing to do with magically fixing classpath problems).

Such files (any number can be found) consist of text; one fully qualified classname per line. The serviceloader loads each stated class by invoking its public constructor (and if that does not exist, that'd be an error; they must be there to use serviceloader).

`NettyChannelProvider` isn't an interface, it is an implementation; you've got things turned about.

If you're really trying to treat NCP as the base interface and you're looking for implementations of it, well, those implementations must [A] be on the runtime classpath as this code is executed or they won't be found, and [B] those implementations must be in jars or other classpath entries that have this META-INF/services/io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelProvider file. If that isn't there, serviceloader doesn't do anything.

That's what serviceloader is: A convenient reader for `META-INF/services/fully.qualified.name.of.the.base.Interface` files.